# capturing events from input/checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I am using [ICheck](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck) for customing my checkboxes. I am having trouble registering events from them. I've been using [this](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks) as a reference for the events that can be triggered.

My checkbox is as follows, where the name is dynamically generated:

```
<input name=<?php echo getname();?> type="checkbox" />
```

Here's my jquery for handling events (just for testing):

```
$('input').on('IfChecked', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
$('input').on('Unchecked', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

The resulting checkbox on the browser is as follows:

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input name="QzpceGFtcHBcaHRkb2NzXG1ldHRhXHVzZXJzXGpvaG5kb2VcTWFpbGRpclxuZXdcMTM5ODE3Mzg4Mi5IOTA1NDI4UDEyMjIxLmRlZGk0NC5jcHQyLmhvc3QtaC5uZXQ1M2E3NGNkYzhiMDJk" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div>
```

However, when I check the checkbox -- nothing happens. The checkbox does not respond. I'm relatively new to javascript, what could be the problem?

Comment: You're capitalising the event names (`IfChecked`), not camelCasing (`ifChecked`); JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: I renamed them, there is still no response.

Comment: Did you initialize `iCheck`? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how your markup and code should look like for the plugin to work. `iCheck` has to be initialized before it can be used.

```
.......
<script src="path-to/jquery"></script>
<script src="path-to/icheck.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input').iCheck(); //minimum initialization

        $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
            alert(event.type + ' callback');
        });
        $('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
            alert(event.type + ' callback');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
<input name="QzpceGFtcHBcaHRkb2NzXG1ldHRhXHVzZXJzXGpvaG5kb2VcTWFpbGRpclxuZXdcMTM5ODE3Mzg4Mi5IOTA1NDI4UDEyMjIxLmRlZGk0NC5jcHQyLmhvc3QtaC5uZXQ1M2E3NGNkYzhiMDJk" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

*Except if you define those events yourself as Custom Events... Unchecked and IfChecked events do not exist.* -> **Sorry, didn't know about ICheck stuff**

Anyway here is how I would do that :

```
$('input').on('change', function(event){
    var $myCheckbox = $(this);
    if($myCheckbox.prop('checked')){
        alert('my checkbox is checked!');
    } else {
        // not checked
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use `this.checked`, it's faster, easier, cheaper and returns a true Boolean. If you *must* use jQuery then you should use `is(':checked')` instead of `prop()`.